# Which version of python time module am I using

Tags: python

How do I determine which version of the python module 'time' is installed. For other modules `.version.version` or `.__version__` work, however for time, both these methods return the error 'module' object has no attribute '**version**' or 'version'

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: time module does not define such names in it. You could check with dir function; `dir(time)` which would give the defined names in that module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module `time` is built-in in the Python interpreter.  No other version than the interpreter's itself can be a valid answer (you can access that one using `sys.version`).

Other built-in modules like `os`, `sys` etc. also do not have their own version information.

Comment: The information on it is very scarce indeed, but looking at the pydocs on the time module you can definitly see a lot of "changed in version 2.2" and such, the latest of them being verison 2.5. Either the module hasn't changed since python 2.5 or it *does* have its own versioning

Comment: While this answer is true for most of the modules that are included with Python, a few, such as `multiprocessing` and `json` also have `__version__` attributes in their namespace. This is usually historical, as those modules used to be packaged independently, and only after they had many releases were they included in the standard library. The version numbers probably are not updated any more (both modules mentioned above have the same version in both Python 2.7 and 3.3), so using `__version__` if it exists may not always be a good idea.

Comment: It will probably have an internal versioning on the developer's site; some git or cvs stuff of course.  But the version numbers mentioned in its `__doc__` refer to the version of the Python interpreter.