# How can I determine library version in Google Collab to determine app's requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip, version

I am using the time library in Python (e.g. time.sleep(initial_delay)) via Google Collab for an ETL I'm making and want to specify it as a requirement for a web app.

Normally, I go to https://pypi.org/search/?q=time&o= and type a library to get the most recent version, but obviously there's 500 pages of time and none are obviously this library.

For some libraries, like pandas, there is this option but not for time:

```
print(time.__version__)
```

```
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute '___version___'
```

I've tried:

```
import time
!pip list
```

But the library time is not in the list.

I've also tried:

```
import time
!pip show time
```

But I get:

```
WARNING: Package(s) not found: time
```

I've also tried:

```
import time
!pip freeze --all
```

But the library time (or any library involving the word 'time') is not there.

How can I see what version of a given library is in use by Python? I just need its version e.g. pandas==1.1.5 for my requirements.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

time module is built-in python. Hence it only changes when your python version changes. and it does not have its own version.

refer to this answer to know more.
[Which version of python time module am I using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951684/which-version-of-python-time-module-am-i-using)

Comment: Does it not need to be implemented in requirements.txt then?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't need the requirement, nor does it need the requirement for socket. Thanks!